# Accessing app_controller functions from within model

Tags: cakephp

I created an elaborate logging and error reporting system for our application's needs, which is interfaced with using a function in the app_controller. I can call this from any controller in the system, as controllers extend the app_controller. What I would like to be able to do is make calls to this function from within model functions. Can anyone advise me on how to do this, or an alternative method for doing such?

Comment: You're not supposed to access controllers from models. Can you describe in more detail what this function does specifically?

Comment: Basically I am wanting a fairly advanced logging functionality that does very detailed logging on the development/qa servers, and less on the production servers. The log entries are given severity ratings (DEBUG, INFO, CRITICAL, etc). I'm wanting to use this from various places in the application code. I prefer using fat-model methodology, but this logging function existing in app_controller, doesn't lend itself to that very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple options:

1. Migrate the logic to the model layer, using a custom AppModel (app/app_model.php). Assuming that all of your controllers as using at least one model, you can call any of your logging functions against any model. ie: `$this->MyModel->customLog('test');`
2. Migrate the logic to a class, store it in app/libs, and load it as needed in your controller or model.

ie:

```
App::import('Lib', 'CustomLog');
$this->CustomLog = new CustomLog(); 
$this->CustomLog->customLog('test');
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that using library functionality would probably be the best way to do this. Thanks for illustrating that.

Comment: One more aspect of this to clarify: I'm hoping I can spawn a call to $this->Session->setFlash() or $this->redirect() from within this function in certain situations. Removing the function from app_controller may not allow the ability to use those... perhaps?

Comment: @Excalibur You should not mix logging logic with user interaction flow logic. Make a controller function that calls your logging code and redirects/flashes when necessary.